# How to escape value of column with reserved name if it's used in conjunction with table alias in Firebird

Tags: sql, firebird

I have table with `add` column. In a table `exportit`. I found that double quoting allows to escape reserved column names, but in my case I need to use aliases because it's a correlated query:

```
SELECT exp_tag.page, exp_tag.tagname, exp_tag.type, "exp_tag.add", exp_tag.mult
 FROM exportit exp_tag
 WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM exportit exp_dev
  WHERE exp_dev.deviceit = exp_tag.deviceit AND scanername = 'webDX(A3)' AND ittablename = '_ISHRSS' AND onoff = 1)
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: `"exp_tag.add"` refers to a column `exp_tag.add` (case-sensitive!), not a column `add`. Both the alias and the column name are separate identifiers, and you need to quote identifiers individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the question by using `exp_tag."ADD"` expression as the column was uppercased and double-quoting is case sensitive.